# maxscript menu .additem no longer working in 2016

Tags: maxscript

I have a init.ms that works fine in max 2014 and 2015, but seems to be broken in 2016? Basically the code just creates an action item and adds it to the main toolbar in max

`if menuMan.registerMenuContext 0x25751c94 then
(
    local myMainMenuBar = menuMan.getMainMenuBar()
    local myRendMenuItem = myMainMenuBar.getItem(9)
    local myRendMenu = myRendMenuItem.getSubMenu()
    local myRendItem = menuMan.createActionItem "RSM" "RSM"
    local mySepItem = menuMan.createSeparatorItem()
    myRendItem.setTitle "Submit"
    myRendItem.setUseCustomTitle true
    myRendMenu.addItem myRendItem 4
    myRendMenu.addItem mySepItem 4
    menuMan.updateMenuBar()
)`

In 2016, it creates the category and action item, you can manually assign it anywhere, but it's not adding it to the toolbar. Has something changed in the way menuMan handles .addItem in 2016?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine here on my end.

Have you ensured, that you have installed the macro in you 3ds max 2016?
You of course also need a macro called "RSM" in a menu called "RSM", for the script to run.

Also, your `registerMenuContext` will prevent you from running this code more than once. Try deleting that part (or generate a new id with `genClassId()`). At least while debugging.